# How to override the "JavaScript Disabled" page on Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want to override the page that gets displayed when a user loads my website but their browser has JavaScript disabled.

Currently when JavaScript is disabled in the browser, my Drupal 7 site just returns a page with this message: **"Sorry, you need to enable JavaScript to visit this website"** .

What is the name of this page that is loaded so I an override it with a custom template I have for such situations?

Edit: 
Drupal version: 7
Base Theme: AdaptiveTheme 7.x-3

Comment: Which theme are you using ? This message inform about your theme functionalities, it need to run javascript to work.

Comment: I am using a custom theme based on the based on AdaptiveTheme 7.x-3 @Fky

Answer (score 0):

Did you try searching for this message string in the codebase? It should help locate the relevant template.

Also, you could set `theme_debug` to `1` ( via drush, it would be `drush vset theme_debug 1`) and then html comments would be added in the source to hint at template usages in different parts of the page.

Comment: I do not have access to the codebase. My Drupal 7 instance is part of API Connect. So I thought maybe there was a template for that No Javascript message page. Coudln't find anything even in the documentation (both Drupal and APIC)

Comment: Could be in a contributed module. For example, it *is* present in [Seckit](https://www.drupal.org/project/seckit). Even if you don't use this module, be sure to check yours.